# Switching from dimmer to single pole, how would I do this?

Tags: electrical, switch, ceiling-fan

[image]

I haven't seen something like this before and was wondering if anyone had any idea how I would switch something like this to a single pole light switch.

Comment: Do you want separate control of the fan and light at this location?

Comment: Can you post a photo looking into the back of the box?

Comment: Is this dimmer on a 3-way switch?

Answer (score 1):

The dimmer wire (Blue) and fan wire (Black) hook to one terminal on your single-pole switch. The hot wire (Black with white Stripe) hooks to the other terminal on your single-pole switch.

Comment: The hot has a white stripe according to the label on the back of the switch, this wire to 1 side of the switch the other 2 wires on the other side of the switch, just commenting for clarity but agree with answer (just don't think it is a fat wire but it may be)+